# Bash piping: split input after 1st line, run different commands on line 1 and the rest

Tags: bash, line, pipe

I have a backup script which copies a file via `ssh` and creates a hash file during transfer. Additionally `pv` is used to display a progress bar:

```
ssh $host "cat '$src_dir/$filename'" \
    | pv --bytes --eta --progress --rate --timer --wait  $opts \
    | tee "$filename" \
    | sha1sum > "$filename.sha1"
```

To display the progress bar correctly I need to pass the size of the file to `pv`. At the moment I do that by giving the size of the last backup file.

It is important that everything is done with 1 `ssh` call because I don't want to authorize multiple times for 1 backup. SSH keys are in use but secured with a passphrase.

My idea is to call `ssh $host "stat -c%s '$src_dir/$filename'; cat '$src_dir/$filename'"` and split the output after the 1st line. I could read the filesize and then call `pv` on the rest of the input.

The backup script is working fine. This is just an exercise for the fun of it. Any ideas are appreciated but I will not completely rewrite the whole script. Especially I won't switch to `scp` because I can't do the hashing during transfer then and I don't want to trust the local storage for that (of course I do, but then why do we do hashing anyway?).

**Update:** I ended up doing this:

```
ssh $host "cd '$src_dir' && stat -c%s '$filename' && sha1sum '$filename' && cat '$filename'" | {
        read size;
        head -n 1 > "$filename.sha1";
        pv --bytes --eta --progress --rate --size $size --timer --wait > "$filename"
    }
```

It works perfectly and has the advantage that the hash is computed at the remote site. So not only before writing to disk but before doing the network transfer.

Comment: If the only reason you want to do this is that you do not want to type the ssh key passphrase multiple times, then you could/should use ssh-agent instead. With ssh-agent you unlock the keys once and let ssh-agent keep track of them (securely). When you are done you can either let the agent be and use it again at the next run, or you can tell it to forget the keys.

Comment: @MikaelAuno: Thank you for your reply. I know about ssh-agent and I'd use it if I had not broke my ssh-agent setup. However I want to share my script with co-workers which don't use ssh-agent for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, I use stat on OSX, which uses z for the format string for size:

```
$ { stat -f %z input; cat input; } | { read s; echo $s; }
```

Replace the first command list with your ssh call, and replace the echo with you pv list, and you are good to go.  In other words, your final command should be:

```
$ ssh $host "stat -c%s '$src_dir/$filename'; cat '$src_dir/$filename'" | {
    read size;
    pv --bytes --eta --progress --rate --timer --wait --size $size |
    tee "$filename" |
    sha1sum; } > "$filename.sha1"
```

I few things to note: I don't have access to pv and did not check the above.
I replaced your line continuations with pipe symbols, because I think
it looks nicer.

Another idea: on the right hand side of the pipe, you could do:

```
{ pv --bytes ... --size $( sed 1q ) |
...
```

This definitely relies on sed not reading past the first newline, and I do not know if that is guaranteed by any standard, but it works with ... oh my, my sed does not support --version, -?, or -h, and I do not know the package management system of OS X well enough to tell you what sed I'm running.  It works with some version of BSD sed...

Comment: That works great! I am pretty surprised that it works with plain bash syntax and without special programs. Note that it's absolutely necessary to use spaces inside the `{}` parentheses and semicolons after each command. Thank you very much for that!

Comment: @halo, you only need a semicolon (or newline or `&`) before the *closing* brace.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the annotation. Actually you can use a newline between the last command and the closing `}` brace, too. For the other semicolons I mentioned: well, you'll need *something* to split the commands;-) Newlines will also do as William showed.